# Polar to cartesian transformation

Tags: polar-coordinates, transformation

I came across an interesting [animation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cartesian_to_polar.gif) the other day.

What's going on here? Why is this possible?

From the author:

A function in the Cartesian plane can be transformed into polar coordinates by wrapping one axis around itself and collapsing it to a point.

1. Start with Cartesian graph.
2. Clip the graph to satisfy $y>0$ (not necessary in the example $y=\sin(6x)+2$).
3. Reflect in the line $y=x$.
4. Bend it to backwards on itself, as shown in the animation, to obtain the polar graph.

What is meant by `bend it backwards on itself` and `wrapping one axis around itself and collapsing it to a point`? Why are steps #2 and #3 necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit tricky to derive the transformation demonstrated in the animation.

Let us start from a point $(x, y)$ of $y = f(x)$. There are two major transformations:

1. $T_1: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}^2 $, $ (a,b) = T_1(x,y)$. Reflection with respect to $y = x$. Therefore, $T_1(x,y) = (y,x)$.
2. $T_2: \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2 $, $ (p,q) = T_2 (a,b)$. Transformation into polar coordinates by wrapping one axis around itself and collapsing it to a point as Wikipedia described. We want to have $(y\cos x, y\sin x) = (T_2 \circ T_1)(x,y)$.

[image]

Let us derive the second transformation in the animation. Let $R > 0$ and consider the circle centered at $(-R, 0)$ with the radius $R+a$. Then, the circle intersects the $x$-axis at $(a, 0)$. Draw a concentric circle with the radius $R+1$. Draw a line segment between $(-R, 0)$ and $(a, 0)$ and rotate it taking $(-R, 0)$ as a pivot, CCW if $b\ge 0$ and CW if $b < 0$, such that the arclength $AB$ equals $|b|$. Therefore, the angle $\theta$ in the figure is $b/(R+1)$. Let $r = (R+a)$. Then, the new coordinate is obtained by
$$
\begin{aligned}
(p,q)
&= (r\cos \theta - R,~r\cos \theta)\\
&= \left((R+a)\cos\dfrac{b}{R+1} -R,~ (R+a)\sin\dfrac{b}{R+1}\right)\\
&= :U_R(a,b)
\end{aligned}
$$
$T_2$ can be thought of as the limit of $U$:
$$
T_2 = \lim_{R \searrow 0} U_R
$$
which follows from the definition of $U$. This is just one of the possible instances of $U$.

Note that $\lim_{R \to \infty}U_R$ is an identity map.

For all $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\lim_{R \searrow 0} U_R(a,b) = (a \cos b, a \sin b)
$$

Comparing the result with the desired one $(y\cos x, y \sin x)$, we know that $T_1$ is indeed needed.

You can think of the circle with the radius $R$ as a bent axis, which collapses to a point (circle degenerates to a point at the origin) as $R \searrow 0$.

The animation shows the result of changing the values of $R$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The graphs 1,3 in the animation have been labelled red OK.

Bending back on itself etc explanation ... introduces imho unnecessary confusion in graph 2 at this stage of learning definition while introducing polar coordinates.

The author is trying to imho explain invariance  of "neutral line" of constant 2 radius in equation $ y=2+ \sin 6 x;\;x- C = \sin ^{-1}(y) \; r = 2+ \sin 6 \theta  ; $ in the respective animation graphs.

Interchanging x-, y- axes is equivalent to defining an *inverse function* $ y=f(x)\to x= f^{-1}(y) $

Sketched in graph 2, $ x-C= \sin^{-1}y$ in which is a multi-valued function... the value $ C=2$ was chosen for illustration.

[image]

Bending back on itself etc... implies that y-axis lines that meet at $ y=-\infty$ are brought together from a single remote point ( parallel lines) gradually reducing the enclosed radius of curvature at reference point from "$\infty$" to 2 units ( in Mechanics beam theory called *uniform bending* where normals to any curve remain normal) for all straight lines between $ (p,q) $ and center $(R,0)$ in Kirchhoff hypothesis where length between two circles and two radial lines of a ring sector remains the same..

A 2-D complex variable mapping can be found if desired.